Fullcalendar, clickEvent, code to "unclick" or revert changes done during clickEvent
While editing events in Fullcalender on a ReactJS website I use a clickEvent to mark or "select" an event. My code is including a lot of extras but an example can be found on fullcalendar.io. Example code:
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

  eventClick: function(info) {
    alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('View: ' + info.view.type);

    // change the border color just for fun
    info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
  }

});

In this code the clicked events border color is set to red. The events standard border color is transparent.
The first event clicked gets red border color. The second event clicked gets red border color. And so on.
The function I am in need of is that when the second event is clicked the border color of the first event is reset to its original state. I.E. When another event is clicked reset the previous one.
For me I have found a couple of solutions:

Solution 1 is working on multi selection. When an event is clicked its border color is set to red. To unselect (unmark with border color) you have to click it again.

Solution 2 is based on storing the event id of the first event. And then to use the fullcalendar API and setExtendedProp to set the border color to transparent of the event with the stored event id. I am not getting result on every click. For me this is unreliable.


Examplecode solution 2:
eventClick={ info =>{
   if (multiSelect === true) {
      if($.inArray(info.event.id, selectedEvents) !== -1) {
         removeAFromArray(selectedEvents, info.event.id);
         info.el.style.borderColor = 'transparent';
      } else {
         addToEventArray(info.event.id);
         info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
      }
  } else {
     let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi();
     selectedEvents.unshift(info.event.id);
     info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';              
     if (selectedEvents.length > 1) {
        let event = calendarApi.getEventById(selectedEvents[1]);
        event.setProp('borderColor', 'transparent');
        selectedEvents.pop()
     }
  }
}}

The code above gives me the function for single click solution 2. But if i am to fast to select the next event it doesnt complete all of the code above. So it visually becomes a multiselect version but it only adds one event to the selectedEvents array.. So more than one event gets red borderColor.

Solution 3 is to start selection with refetch events. Then set the border color of the selected event when the events are refetched. This resets all events. This is not preferable. I just want to reset the previous event.

What is the next solution. Is there a better way?



Solution 2, instead of storing the event ID and looking it up via the API, can't you store info directly? And then you check, if (storedInfo && storedInfo.el), to see if you have any previous event to restore to its un-selected state. And if storedInfo.el == info.el, then you don't need to select the current one.

I am not getting result on every click. For me this is unreliable...really? Can you provide a [mre] of that issue? Please [edit] your question. We can't fix a problem if you don't show us

As above, please [edit] your question if you need to provide updates. Don't attempt to add code into the comment area
